# How to capture a CSS multiline comment block with JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, node.js

I'm trying to capture a CSS multiline comment block with a JavaScript regex but I'm not sure how to find the closing comment tag without get occasional slashes inside HTML examples, this is one case:

```
/*@comment

    @title: Buttons
    @name: block-name
    @category: Category name > Sub category
    @description: This is the description of the element
    @html:
        <div class="block-name"></div>

*/
```

I'm trying with this regex but I arrive at the closing div tag:

`\/\*@comment([^\*\/]){1,}`

So I tryied adding the ending comment tag and it's just stop working:

`\/\*@comment([^\*\/]){1,}\*\/`

How can I find a JavaScript regex to capture the entire block?

Note that I can find more than one of these blocks per file, so I'll use the `g` tag on the regex.

Comment: [`\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/hH8gO1/1).

Comment: @MaxMastalerz `'a/*b*/c/*d*/'.match(/\/\*([^;]*)\*\//g)` produces `["/*b*/c/*d*/"]` instead of `["/*b*/", "/*d*/"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `([^\*\/]){1,}` only matches 1 or more *individual* characters other than `*` or `/`, not as a sequence of 2 characters.

You can use lazy matching (`*?` quantifier matching as few characters as possible to ensure a match is found) with `[^]` or `[\s\S]` (classes that match any character including a newline):

```
/\/\*@comment[\s\S]*?\*\//g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH8gO1/2)

```js
var re = /\/\*@comment[\s\S]*?\*\//g; 
var str = '/*@comment\n\n    @title: Buttons\n    @name: block-name\n    @category: Category name > Sub category\n    @description: This is the description of the element\n    @html:\n        <div class="block-name"></div>\n\n*/';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

I prefer `[\s\S]` to `[^]` as the latter is only supported by JavaScript regex engine.

Comment: You could also use [`\/\*@comment(?:(?!\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/hH8gO1/3) regex version with a tempered greedy token, but I doubt there is any reason for you to use it here, since there are no additional words that you "forbid" in the match.